# Google Shopping REST API: strategies for avoiding spurious results

Tags: rest, google-shopping-api

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867464/google-shopping-rest-api-restricting-by-category) and [this forum post](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-search-api-for-shopping/ndUxvH4i3mU), it's not possible to use the google taxonomy when filtering searches by category.

I am using the shopping API to search for laptops, and am frustrated by the vast array of non-laptops results I am getting.  These results include batteries, screens, memory upgrades, hard drives, CPUs, motherboards, etc.

Does anyone have any creative ideas for `restrictBy` or `boostBy` parameters that will in general favor whole laptops over their components?